# Azure IOT ExportDevicesAsync internal server error

Tags: azure, iot, azure-iot-hub

Same problem as [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42651680/azure-iothub-exportdevicesasync-throws-internal-server-error/). I'm following the [simple sample to export the IOT](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/iot-hub/iot-hub-bulk-identity-mgmt#export-devices) device list to blob storage but hitting an internal server error on ExportDevicesAsync. 
I'm using North Europe, but I don't think changing servers is really a valid fix.

All I'm getting back is:

```
An exception of type 'Microsoft.Azure.Devices.Common.Exceptions.ServerErrorException' occurred in mscorlib.dll but was not handled in user code

Additional information: {"Message":"ErrorCode:ServerError;InternalServerError","ExceptionMessage":"Tracking ID:c51dad0227604f21b9af3e8acbd77f4c-G:5-TimeStamp:06/03/2017 19:56:10"}
```

Sample Code (connection strings and keys masked)

```
internal async Task GetAllDevices()
{

    var ConnectionString =
        "HostName=xxxx.azure-devices.net;SharedAccessKeyName=xxxxowner;SharedAccessKey=xxxxLr3xxxxXKKILLxxxxx";
   registryManager = RegistryManager.CreateFromConnectionString(ConnectionString);

    var key = "https://xxxxotblob1.blob.core.windows.newt/?sv=2016-05-31&ss=bfqt&srt=sco&sp=rwdlxxxxup&se=2017-06-04T04:42:14Z&st=2017-06-03T20:42:14Z&spr=https&sig=kxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx%3D";

    JobProperties exportJob = await registryManager.ExportDevicesAsync(key,"device.txt", false);

    while (true)
    {
        exportJob = await registryManager.GetJobAsync(exportJob.JobId);
        if (exportJob.Status == JobStatus.Completed ||
            exportJob.Status == JobStatus.Failed ||
            exportJob.Status == JobStatus.Cancelled)
        {
            break;
        }

        await Task.Delay(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(5));
    }

}
```

Am I doing something wrong here? Is there a way to catch the real exception I'm missing?

Comment: Which line cause this exception?

Comment: @RitaHan-MSFT it was on line : JobProperties exportJob = await registryManager.ExportDevicesAsync(key,"device.txt", false);

Answer (score 1):

You may have wrong format of the exportBlobContainerUri. The right one looks like this:

```
https://[StorageAccountName].blob.core.windows.net/[ContainerName]?sv=2016-05-31&sr=c&sig=mxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxw%3D&se=2017-06-06T02%3A07%3A22Z&sp=rwd
```

You can follow these steps to get the container SAS URI:

```
//1# Get your container:

CloudStorageAccount storageAccount = CloudStorageAccount.Parse(
    CloudConfigurationManager.GetSetting("StorageConnectionString"));

CloudBlobClient blobClient = storageAccount.CreateCloudBlobClient();

CloudBlobContainer container = blobClient.GetContainerReference("mycontainer");

//2# Format the Uri:

static string GetContainerSasUri(CloudBlobContainer container)
{
  var sasConstraints = new SharedAccessBlobPolicy();
  sasConstraints.SharedAccessExpiryTime = DateTime.UtcNow.AddHours(24);
  sasConstraints.Permissions = 
    SharedAccessBlobPermissions.Write | 
    SharedAccessBlobPermissions.Read | 
    SharedAccessBlobPermissions.Delete;

  string sasContainerToken = container.GetSharedAccessSignature(sasConstraints);

  return container.Uri + sasContainerToken;
}
```

For more information you can reference [Create a container](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/storage/storage-dotnet-how-to-use-blobs#create-a-container) and [Get the container SAS URI](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/iot-hub/iot-hub-bulk-identity-mgmt#get-the-container-sas-uri).